# profile2 image field not show images

Tags: 7, users

I tested my profile2 image field at upload moment and the file upload successfully and unexpectedly after save changes the image fid appears like 0 but the image don't show.

What I do?

Thanks!

Comment: I see that profile2 image field don't save on field_data_field_name with fid. I see that the image is saved on file_managed also. Why happend?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that I have an module conflict, if you decide to use DDF (Dynamic Dependent Fields) you must think before make tests with profile2 fields.